# Min/Max of pgfplots@data@xmin and \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}

Tags: pgfplots, errors

Following example does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot  coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
    \node (A) at ({rel axis cs:0.25,0.25}) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}};
    \node (B) at ({rel axis cs:0.75,0.75}) {\pgfplots@data@xmin};
    \node (C) at ({rel axis cs:0.5,0.5}) {\pgfmathparse{min(\pgfplots@data@xmin,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin})} \pgfmathresult};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
line 14 error| Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `Y' or `Y9' (in 'min(1Y9.48e-4],7.427876e-4)').
```

if I disable `\node (C)` it works.

I do not understand why the return value of `\pgfplots@data@xmin` looks so strange.

Comment: It's the fpu representation of a number. Pgfplots use it by default but TikZ doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As percusse said in the comment, that's the floating point representation that's used by PGFPlots. To make your code work, add `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}` before the `\pgfmathparse` command to switch on the floating point math parser. To print the result using the conventional representation, either use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` to format the number, or set `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` to use a fixed point output format.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot  coordinates {(948e-6,1.61981) (1.5e-3,1.02377) (2e-3,0.769047) (2.5e-3,0.614994) (3e-3,0.503511)};
    \node (A) at ({rel axis cs:0.25,0.25}) {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}};
    \node (B) at ({rel axis cs:0.75,0.75}) {\pgfplots@data@xmin};
    \node (C) at ({rel axis cs:0.5,0.5}) {
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{min(\pgfplots@data@xmin,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin})}
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. One minor question: how I can I format the node B to look identical to node C?

Comment: And if you know where I could have found this information in the pgf/tikz or pgfplots documentation, you could add the respective location in the docs to your answer.