# Percentages in nodes near coords, tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I want to set percentages in de nodes near coords. So for example 0.33 becomes 33% in stead of 0.33%. At this point it does sets a percentage sign after the node. Can somebody help me?

```latex
{
    \begin{figure}[h!]

    \centering


    \resizebox {0.45\textwidth} {!} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=1,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={Gearing},
        yticklabel ={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%},
        symbolic x coords={Vorig jaar,Huidig jaar},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\,\%},
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        bar width = 1.5cm,
        ymajorgrids =true,
        ]
    \addplot[fill ,color=ZandersGreen] 
        coordinates {(Vorig jaar,-0.33) (Huidig jaar,1.5)};


    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{Gearing vergeleken met de benchmark (links) en over tijd (rechts)\VAR{n5excepPlot}}
    \end{figure}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please make your example compilable, so that we can help you !

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87431/184389) gives you the solution. It suggests to add `point meta = {x*100}` to the `axis` environment options. However, be careful, since you have the value as second argument of the coordinates, you have to replace this instruction by `point meta = {y*100}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do [(being careful)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187816/38080) do some calculation in the `pgfplots` keys...

If you change your `nodes near coordinates` to:

```latex
nodes near coords={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%},
```

You have this (after fighting a bit to compile your example) — please, next time follow [the instructions to build a minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers